# java pdf in i need a box for the amount value for 25000

Tags: java, pdf, itext

```
Chunk amountLabel = new Chunk("Amount: ");
amountLabel.setFont(smallBold);
Chunk amountValue = new Chunk("Rs 25,000/-");
amountValue.setUnderline(0.1f, -2f); //0.1 thick, -2 y-location
amountValue.setFont(small);
Phrase phrase4 = new Phrase();
phrase4.add(amountLabel);
phrase4.add(amountValue);
PdfPCell cell5 = new PdfPCell(phrase4);
cell5.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
cell5.setPadding(padding);
cell5.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
table.addCell(cell5);
```

In this I need a square box for the amount value while generating a pdf through java by using itext can any one please help me

Comment: I'm going to guess it has something to do with this? 
cell5.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

Comment: Hi here i need borders for only amounntvalue(i.e for 25000/-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a border for the cell, you only want a border for a specific ´Chunk´. This can be achieved by using a page event, more specifically a [generic tag event](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=206). Please that a look at [movie_years.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part1/chapter05/movie_years.pdf). Where you see the year a movie was produced, you have a movie strip in the background; where you see IMDB, a blue oval is shown.

Now take a look at the [generic tag code](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=97). You need to extend the `PdfPageEventHelper` class and implement the `onGenericTag()` method. Use the `rect` parameter to draw a rectangle. Create an instance of your custom page event helper (e.g. `event`) and declare it to the writer:

```
writer.setPageEvent(event);
```

Now set the generic tag for every ´Chunk´ that needs a rectangle. For instance:

```
amountValue.setGenericTag("some_tag_of_your_choice");
```

Now whenever such a ´Chunk´ is rendered, the `onGenericTag()` method will be executed.